# Need Ghidra to Auto Analyze common Microsoft C Functions

Tags: reverse-engineering, malware, ida, ghidra

Fellow Reverse Engineerers,

I've been using Ghidra for quite some time now and I began realizing that there are certain functions, like rand and wcscpy, that Ghidra just will not auto analyze and will not auto populate (see attached picture).

How can we get Ghidra to automatically label common Microsoft C Functions like IDA Pro does?  I'm getting tired of Reverse Engineering commonly known functions in Ghidra.

[image: Ghidra vs IDA Pro's Functions]

Comment: Are you searching FLIRT for ghidra (https://github.com/NWMonster/ApplySig)?

Comment: No, I am not. But, you did give me some good Google search terms that led me to a YouTube video helped me do something similiar. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cei3I7lr9go